# How to response S3 image object in Fastify

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fastify

I tried to response the image stream from S3 in but couldn't success. In Express.js the below code work perfectly fine but it doesn't work in Fastify.

```
const imageObject = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
imageObject.pipe(res);
```

My Fastify route code which I named it file-upload.ts

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

const fileUploadRoutes = async (fastify: any) => {
  fastify.route({
    method: ["GET"],
    url: "/img/:type/:image",
    logLevel: "warn",
    handler: async (req: any, reply: any) => {
      try {
        const params = req.params;

        const getParams = {
          Bucket: BucketName,
          Key: `${params.type}/${params.image}` /* path & file name */
        };

        const imageObject = await s3.getObject(getParams).createReadStream();

        reply.send(imageObject);
      } catch (err) {
        reply.send(err);
      }
    }
  });
};

export default fileUploadRoutes;
```

and here is my app.ts

```
import Fastify, { FastifyInstance } from "fastify";

// Routes
import fileUploadRoutes from "./routes/file-upload";

const app: FastifyInstance = Fastify({ logger: true });

// Register Media File Content
app.register(import("@fastify/multipart"), {
  attachFieldsToBody: true,
  limits: { fileSize: 770000 }
});

// Upload File Routes
app.register(fileUploadRoutes);

export default app;
```

Comment: did you try `reply.send(imageObject)`?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I did, but image still doesn't show as it is in Express.js

Comment: Focus on your target, not on that in express it works. You have omitted all the fastify code, so could you add more code? What is the client getting? Did you configure the response schema? What is the `imageObject` type? Is it a stream?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon sorry, I edited and added code. I use fastify along with @fastify/multipart and there's no schema. For the client I plan to let them access through the /img/:type/:image endpoint

Comment: I'd expect the code to be like: `const data = await s3.getObject(getParams).promise(); const stream = data.createReadStream();`